# Configure sender address for all users in mutt

Tags: email, mutt

I have CentOS running mutt. When mails are sent from mutt (via a shell script), it takes the current user name as sender address causing it to go into the spam.

I receive mail as

```
From: tech
```

What I need is:

```
From:    tech@myserver.com
```

All I need is a single place change that reflects everwhere. i.e. if I send from the root user, the from address should be `root@myserver.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a system-wide mutt RC file? Perhaps it is here: `/etc/mutt/Muttrc`?
Within the file, set the hostname with `set hostname=myserver.com`.

Comment: It worked.. However it is giving the from address as  tech@myserver.co.in  via otherdomain.com